# select from table where column a is not equal column b (on same table) and tableID = 2

Tags: php, mysql

`select from table where column a is not equal column b (on same table) and tableID = 2`

Any one who can give me a simple code on this .

```
<?php
$query_myslot = "select from table where column a is not equal column b (on same table) and tableID = 2";
$myslot = mysql_query($query_myslot, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_myslot = mysql_fetch_assoc($myslot);
$totalRows_myslot = mysql_num_rows($myslot);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your query as below :

```
select * from tablename where column1 <> column2  and tableID = 2
```

Comment: select * from tablename where column1 <> column2  and tableID = 2 works perfect,

Comment: Please give the question an up vote it has disturbed many like me